# Trying to filter a JSON in order to retrieve the parent based on characteristics of the children

Tags: json, filtering

Based on the bellow JSON im trying to extract the "DrugReleaseId" for a child that holds the PickNrRangeBegin==558 and PickNrRangeEnd==559.

```
"Data":[
  {
     "DrugReleaseId":"8a7bb731-8802-11ec-8ba3-00505699a442",
     "Filters":[
        {
           "BulkBatch2LotIds":null,
           "DrugCodeId":"1",
           "DrugDescription":"Druggy - 10mg 28 tablets",
           "PickNrRangeBegin":558,
           "PickNrRangeEnd":559,
           "Quantity":null,
           "TemporaryUnavailable":null,
           "LotIds":[
              "ed65aa20-e3b7-11eb-8b9b-00505699a442"
           ]
        },
        {
           "BulkBatch2LotIds":null,
           "DrugCodeId":"2",
           "DrugDescription":"Placebo - 10mg 28 tablets",
           "PickNrRangeBegin":25505,
           "PickNrRangeEnd":25506,
           "Quantity":null,
           "TemporaryUnavailable":null,
           "LotIds":[
              "98025036-e92c-11eb-8b9b-00505699a442"
           ]
        }
     ],
     "DepotId":"01",
     "LotId":"b7179175-e92c-11eb-8b9b-00505699a442",
     "LabelGroupId":null,
     "CreatedByUserId":"8509960e-8181-4428-89bd-367c0be29a9a",
     "CreatedUtcDateTime":"Mon Feb 07 2022 00:00:00",
     "Status":0,
     "ProcessedByUserId":null,
     "ProcessedUtcDateTime":null
  }
```

I've only got to $..Data.[?(@.PickNrRangeBegin=='558') && ?(@.PickNrRangeBegin=='559')] but this will return all the contained elements:

```
"BulkBatch2LotIds": null,
"DrugCodeId": "1",
"DrugDescription": "BAY123456 - 10mg 28 tablets",
"PickNrRangeBegin": 558,
"PickNrRangeEnd": 559,
"Quantity": null,
"TemporaryUnavailable": null,
"LotIds": [
  "ed65aa20-e3b7-11eb-8b9b-00505699a442"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to apply the filter expression to the Data object itself, not its children.  You'd think this should be...

```
$..Data[?(@.Filters[*].PickNrRangeBegin == 558 && @.Filters[*].PickNrRangeEnd == 559)].DrugReleaseId
```

... but that still doesn't quite work.

Here's a simpler expression that also "ought" to work:

```
$..Data[?(@..PickNrRangeBegin == 558 && @..PickNrRangeEnd == 559)].DrugReleaseId
```

I think the fact that these aren't working is a weakness of the particular jsonpath parser implementations.  I just tried this last expression on https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/, which tries 4 different implementations.  The Gatling parser actually gets the correct answer!  But Jayway finds no result, and the other two throw errors.  Sigh.

Comment: Yeah. Ive tried that but it doesn't work indeed